# Derivative of the inverse of a matrix in regards to a product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse, matrix-calculus

I am having problem with:

$$ \frac{\delta AX^{-1}B}{\delta X} =   \space ? $$

What I did is the following:

$$ I = XX^{-1} $$
$$ \frac{\delta AXX^{-1}B}{\delta X}=A \frac{\delta X}{\delta X}X^{-1}B + AX \frac{\delta X^{-1}}{\delta X}B $$
$$  AX \frac{\delta X^{-1}}{\delta X}B = -A\frac{\delta X}{\delta X}X^{-1}B $$
$$ (A) (AX)^{-1}  AX \frac{\delta X^{-1}}{\delta X}B = -(A)(AX)^{-1}A \frac{\delta X}{\delta X}X^{-1}B $$
$$  A \frac{\delta X^{-1}}{\delta X}B = -AX^{-1} \frac{\delta X}{\delta X}X^{-1}B  $$
$$ \frac{\delta AX^{-1}B}{\delta X} =  -AX^{-1}X^{-1}B $$

But in the Matrix Cookbook the result for inverse of a trace is:

$$ \frac{\delta tr(AX^{-1}B)}{\delta X} = -(X^{-1}BAX^{-1}){T} $$

From which I conclude that it should be

$$ \frac{\delta AX^{-1}B}{\delta X} = -X^{-1}BAX^{-1} $$

And I cannot find the reason why the BA is inside and switched places  and please do not use frobenious product for solution.

Comment: matrices can by cyclicly permuted inside the trace

Comment: How can the derivative of a matrix with respect to a matrix be a matrix?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo What exactly do you mean?

Comment: The gradient of every entry of the matrix output with respect to the matrix input is a matrix. In other words, you need $4$ indices, i.e., a $4$-dimensional matrix to store all the partial derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative to greg's fourth-order tensor, one can vectorize and exploit Kronecker products.

Using differential result of greg's solution, that is,
\begin{align}
dY = -\underbrace{AX^{-1}}_{:=\color{blue}{\widetilde{A}}} \ \color{red}{dX} \ \underbrace{X^{-1}B}_{:=\color{green}{\widetilde{B}}} := -\color{blue}{\widetilde{A}} \ \color{red}{dX} \ \color{green}{\widetilde{B}},
\end{align}
we now [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) both sides such that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{vec}\left(dY\right) = -\operatorname{vec}\left(\color{blue}{\widetilde{A}} \ \color{red}{dX} \ \color{green}{\widetilde{B}}\right) = -\left(\color{green}{\widetilde{B}}^T \otimes \color{blue}{\widetilde{A}}\right) \operatorname{vec}\left(\color{red}{dX}\right).
\end{align}

Then, the gradient can be written as
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} =  -\left(\color{green}{\widetilde{B}}^T \otimes \color{blue}{\widetilde{A}}\right) .
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
$The gradient of a matrix with respect to itself can be written in component form using the single-entry matrix $E_{ij}$ all of whose elements equal zero except the $(i,j)$ element which equals $\o$.
$$\eqalign{
\grad{X}{X_{ij}} &=E_{ij} \\
}$$
This can be used to calculate the element-wise gradient of the function
$$\eqalign{
Y &= AX^{-1}B \\
dY &= A\;\c{dX^{-1}}B = A\,\c{\Big(\!-\!X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1}\Big)}B \\
\grad{Y}{X_{ij}} &=  -AX^{-1}E_{ij}\,X^{-1}B \\
}$$
The full gradient is a fourth-order tensor, which can be written as the sum of the dyadic products $(\star)$ of these matrix components with the corresponding single-entry matrix
$$\eqalign{
\grad{Y}{X}
 &= \sum_{i=\o}^n\sum_{j=\o}^n\LR{\grad{Y}{X_{{ij}}}}\star E_{{ij}} \\
}$$

Comment: Your example is the second method that I also used to derive the solution, so does that mean that it is correct -AX^-1X^-1B? In the Matrix Cookbook there are examples only for trace and with a and b as vectors

Comment: @Engineeringbridges No, your result is a matrix whereas the actual gradient is a fourth-order tensor. To get a matrix result you must either use components, or vectorize as shown in user550103's  answer.